# $and condition in php causing Uncaught exception 'MongoException' with message 'Invalid object ID'

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb

I have a selection criteria in $Select which selects a document.The document has username and a couple of other document's object id.After selecting the document it searches for "Another_id" field and stores it in $Another_id variable

```
 $Select = array("Username"=>$user, "SomeOther_id"=>$SomeOtherDocID);
 $doc = $db->$collection->find($Select);  
 foreach($doc as $o=>$a) {   
      foreach($a as $k=>$v) {
        if($k=="Another_id")
        echo $Another_id=$v;

      }
 }

$a_id=array("_id"=>new MongoId($Another_id));
```

Now $Another_id being an object_id will have it's own document in it's own collection. So to access that another collection document i've got to convert $Another_id to Object id in the last line.

Here I'm getting error:  Uncaught exception 'MongoException' with message 'Invalid object ID'

I believe it's because the selection criteria $Select is not working as 
echo $Another_id; does not output anything.

How to solve this error?

Comment: If you know that there is no value in `$Another_id` then perhaps check whether the document result has a key for `Another_id` ? `MongoId` construct accepts an id such as '56f0c7206db0ef302c81b721' .Also see [MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-bson-objectid.php)